# How to populate boost recursive map container

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary

I try to use the following [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html#container.containers_of_incomplete_types.recursive_containers) from boost:

```
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
struct data
{
    std::string label;
    //A map holding still undefined 'data'
    boost::container::map<std::string, data> m_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    data d,d1,d2;
    d.m_["hello"] = d1;
    return 0;
}
```

unfortunately it does not compile and I can't figure why.

Compilers Message (just the end of it):
../../3d_party_4_5_8/boost_1_49_0/boost/container/detail/tree.hpp|183| error: no match for גoperator=ג in ג((boost::container::container_detail::rbtree_node, std::allocator >, data>, void*>*)this)->boost::container::container_detail::rbtree_node, std::allocator >, data>, void*>::m_data.boost::container::container_detail::pair, std::allocator >, data>::second = p->boost::container::container_detail::pair, std::allocator >, data>::secondג
Analyzer.cpp|139| note: candidates are: data& data::operator=(data&)

Comment: Did it possibly occur to you that it might be helpful to include the compiler error message in your question?!

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`?

Comment: Are you compiling in C++03 mode?

Comment: Yes, I can't use c++11, but I don't see c++11 here or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ezra: `boost::container` uses move emulation in C++03 mode, this is one of the limitations to it (see link in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are compiling in C++03 mode:
Please see [Assignment operator in classes derived from or holding copyable and movable types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/move/emulation_limitations.html#move.emulation_limitations.assignment_operator). Your assignment operator is **non-const** as shown in the error message: `data& data::operator=(data&)`, this is the problem. `boost::container` emulates move semantics in C++03 compilers, and in order to do this defines a non-const copy constructor. One possible solution is too add the following to `data`:

```
data& operator=(data x)
{
    std::swap(*this, x); 
    return *this;
}
```

or

```
data& operator=(const data& x)
{
    label = x.label 
    return *this;
}
```

depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I never thought that that were possible. But it is indeed. Try this for inserting:

```
//...
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    data d,d1,d2;
    d.m_.insert( std::make_pair(std::string("hello"), d1) ) ;
    return 0;
}
// ...
```

... it works even in C++03.